# Is there any way I can find all macro expansion location?

Tags: clang, libtooling

I want to find all macro expansion location to replace the definition of macro.

I don't know what API I can use to get the macro expansion location.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 5
int main(void)
{ 
  int i;
  int j = NUM;
  int a[NUM] = {0};
  printf("请输入%d个数:", j);
  for(i=0; i<NUM; ++i) {
    scanf("%d", &a[i] );
  }
  for(i=0; i<NUM; ++i) {
    printf("%d\x20", a[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I want to find all macro expansion location and replace them with 5.(4 location)

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#define NUM 5
int main(void)
{
            int i;
            int j = NUM;
            int a[NUM] = {0};
            printf("请输入%d个数:", j);
            for(i=0; i<NUM; ++i){
                scanf("%d", &a[i] );
            }
            for(i=0; i<NUM; ++i){
                printf("%d\x20", a[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            return 0;
}

Comment: I want to find all expansion location of NUM, such as  int j = NUM;

Comment: I've answered a pretty similar answer in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58658020/11582326