# How to get the macro and its expansion with clang libtooling?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, libtooling

I am working on clang libtooling.

So far I am managed to get the macro where it is getting referred in the source file through `visitDeclRefExpr(DeclRefExpr *DR)`

But can I get  a list of macros with its name and its expansion as string.

exampleprogram.c

```
#define abc ab

#define sum 0

int main()
{
int ab;
abc  = abc + 0;
return 0;
}
```

can I get the output like the following

```
abc -- ab

sum -- 0
```

How can I achieve this output with clang libtooling. How  can I implement with the clang libtooling?

Please let me know if solution is available for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

In AST, unfortunately, Clang stores bare minimum information on macros. `SourceLocation` contains some information on which macros had been expanded there. You can find more information on locations and macro expansions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512050/clang-how-to-get-the-macro-name-used-for-size-of-a-constant-size-array-declarat/56513459#56513459).

In order to get access to macro definitions and expansions (visit them as you visit AST nodes, so to speak), you need to use Clang's preprocessor. [PPCalbacks](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1PPCallbacks.html) is the right tool to do it. You can get `Preprocessor` from `CompilerInstance` ([CompilerInstance::getPreprocessor](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CompilerInstance.html#a1ac2ca1acff919eb06ecf8ccdc680e99)) and hook your callbacks into it.

I hope this information is useful. Happy hacking with Clang!

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve macro info from serialized AST?